# UIRemoteNotification received time

Tags: ios, push-notification

In my app a remote notification is valid only for few seconds. Now if user clicks on some old notification. Is their a way i can get what time a notification received.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing like that built-in by default but you can simply add your own timestamp value in the payload. This is of course provided you are the one configuring and sending the push notifications in the first place.

One thing to keep in mind is that notifications are limited to 256 bytes in the payload and will fail otherwise, so make sure yours don't go over that. [Documentation here.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html)

Comment: In iOS8 the limit was increased to 2KB payload!